# Titanium Studio Android Emulator does not start MacBook

Tags: android-emulator, osx-lion

I built a very basic app, i am a newbee, code is below. the app is working fin in iOS but nothing happens when i try to lunch it on the android emulator. I have a file with all the error, about 40, but I cannot upload the file here there are.

system info: MacBook Pro version 10.7.3, Xcode 4.3,

Titanium Studio, build: 2.1.0.201205041150 (c) Copyright 2012 by Appcelerator, Inc. All rights reserved.

Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-development-707 (origin/development) Date: 04 May 2012, 11:51:06

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

```
    // this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('red');

var isAndroid = false;
if (Titanium.Platform.name == 'android') {
    isAndroid = true;
}

var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: 'Test Dropzone Database',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
});

var inputTextContinentName = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    hintText:'Select One Continent',
    top: 50,
    left: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    editable: true,
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_LINE,
});

var queryButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Get Region',
    top: 90,
    left: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    backgroundFocusedColor: 'blue',
//  backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: 'black'
});

var textAreaAnswer = Titanium.UI.createTextArea({
    value : 'I am a textarea',
//  color : '#888',
    top: 130,
    left: 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    editable: false,
    textAlign : 'left',
//      borderWidth : 2,
    borderColor : 'black',
//  borderRadius : 5
});

win.add(inputTextContinentName);
win.add(queryButton);
win.add(textAreaAnswer);
win.open()

>[ERROR][Netd    (   33)] Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
>[ERROR][Netd    (   33)] Unable to open quota2 logging socket
>[ERROR][PhonePolicy(   37)] Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
>[ERROR][BatteryService(   85)] usbOnlinePath not found
>[ERROR][BatteryService(   85)] batteryVoltagePath not found
>[ERROR][BatteryService(   85)] batteryTemperaturePath not found
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)] Error reporting WTF
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)] java.lang.NullPointerException
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.wtf(RuntimeInit.java:345)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at android.util.Log$1.onTerribleFailure(Log.java:103)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:278)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.getNetworkStatsDetailGroupedByUid(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5738)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.access$100(BatteryStatsImpl.java:76)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.computeCurrentTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2457)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.getTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2446)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeSummaryToParcel(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5437)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4836)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeAsyncLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4818)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.<init>(ActivityManagerService.java:1489)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.<init>(ActivityManagerService.java:150)
>[ERROR][AndroidRuntime(   85)]     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1390)
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)] A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)] java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)]     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)]     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)]     at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.readUserList(UserManager.java:114)
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)]     at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:81)
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)]     at com.android.server.pm.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:85)
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)]     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:923)
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)]     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:833)
>[ERROR][StrictMode(   85)]     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:163)
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
>[ERROR][EventHub(   85)] could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
>[ERROR][EventHub(   85)] could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
>[ERROR][CommandListener(   33)] Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
>[ERROR][WifiStateMachine(   85)] Failed to disable IPv6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate to native daemon for disabling ipv6
>[ERROR][MobileDataStateTracker(   85)] default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
>[ERROR][MobileDataStateTracker(   85)] default: Could not enable APN type "default"
>[ERROR][ActivityThread(  175)] Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
>[ERROR][BinaryDictionaryGetter(  175)] Could not find a dictionary pack
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
>[ERROR][SoundPool(   85)] error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
>[ERROR][DefaultVoicemailNotifier(  366)] No voicemails to notify about: clear the notification.
>[ERROR][TiApplication(  612)] (KrollRuntimeThread) [3124,3212] APP PROXY: ti.modules.titanium.app.AppModule@4103c728
```

Comment: It fixed after latest update, i hope